# Cocatenate columns uniquely on the same table in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

The Original Table:

```
=======================================================================================
|   A   |     B    |       C        |     D     |     E     |      F      |     G     |
=======================================================================================
| 65432  | AFD452E |   sometext1    |   IA1     |   10,6    |    8,5      |   22,0    |
| 65432  | AFD452E |   sometext1    |   IA2     |           |    11,4     |   16,5    |
| 65432  | AFD452E |   sometext1    |   IA3     |           |    3,5      |    5,3    |
| 65989  | 74652E  |   sometext2    |   IA1     |   3,3     |             |     8     |
| 65989  | 74652E  |   sometext2    |   IA3     |   23      |     1,1     |    6,9    |
| 27890  | P8965A  |   sometext3    |   IA3     |   12,7    |     13,8    |   33,2    |
=======================================================================================
```

The resulting Table should be:

```
=======================================================================================
|   A   |     B    |       C        |     NEWA1     |     NEWA2     |      NEWA3      |
=======================================================================================
| 65432  | AFD452E |   sometext1    | 10,6-8,5-22,0-| -11,4-16,5-   |                 |
| 65989  | 74652E  |   sometext2    | 3,3--8-       |               |  23-1,1-6,9-    |
| 27890  | P8965A  |   sometext3    |               |               | 12,7-13,8-33,2- |
=======================================================================================
```

This is what I have came up with so far but it does not do the job:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT [A], [B], [C],
    IIF( [D]  LIKE  "IA1",  IIF(ISNULL([E]), '-', [E] + '-') + IIF(ISNULL([F]), '-', [F] + '-')  + IIF(ISNULL([G]), '-', [G] + '-')   , ‘’) AS NEWIA1,  
    IIF( [D]  LIKE  "IA2",  IIF(ISNULL([E]), '-', [E] + '-') + IIF(ISNULL([F]), '-', [F] + '-')  + IIF(ISNULL([G]), '-', [G] + '-')   , ‘’) AS NEWIA2, 
    IIF( [D]  LIKE  "IA3",  IIF(ISNULL([E]), '-', [E] + '-') + IIF(ISNULL([F]), '-', [F] + '-')  + IIF(ISNULL([G]), '-', [G] + '-')   , ‘’) AS NEWIA3
    FROM TABLE;
```

This is what I came up with my query :

```
=======================================================================================
|   A   |     B    |       C        |     NEWA1     |     NEWA2     |      NEWA3      |
=======================================================================================
| 65432  | AFD452E |   sometext1    | 10,6-8,5-22,0-|               |                 |
| 65432  | AFD452E |   sometext1    |               |  -11,4-16,5-  |                 |
| 65432  | AFD452E |   sometext1    |               |               |   -11,4-16,5-   |
| 65989  | 74652E  |   sometext2    | 3,3--8-       |               |                 |
| 65989  | 74652E  |   sometext2    |               |               |   23-1,1-6,9-   |
| 27890  | P8965A  |   sometext3    |               |               | 12,7-13,8-33,2- |
=======================================================================================
```

Comment: We need to see what you've done. There are a few options to get you what you need.

Comment: Does someone has an idea of how this can be achieved ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you working in VBA, not the graphical interface?

Comment: Im using the powerpivot import tool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select A, B, C,
max(iif([D] like "1A1" .. rest of code)) as newa1,
e ...
from table
group by A, B. c;
```

Once you get the rows set up, you could wrap them inside a subquery and trim the excess hyphens.

Comment: Thank you, 
 but it also brought me rows from the original table I did not display earlier where column D has values other than IA1 and IA2 and IA3 like : | 34432 | P673452 | sometext3 | IA6 | | | | | 55770 | 27799A | sometext4 | IA7 | | | | 
 How to avoid rows when col D is not IA1 and IA2 and IA3 ?

Comment: Basically what I want to add is that the resulting columns NEWA1 and NEWA2 and NEWA3 should not be all : empty, or null or zero lenght  as the same time.

Comment: All my congrat to all of you the question has been fully answered with that query. Thank you very much to all! :)

SELECT
  A, B, C, ...
FROM
  YourTable
WHERE
  D IN ('IA1', 'IA2', 'IA3')
GROUP BY
  A, B, C
;

Comment: One last thing :) Is it possible to add a new column in the result let's say SumTotal which sould be the SUM of any occurences in column G for the same value in column A no matter if column D is IN ('IA1', 'IA2', 'IA3'). I have tried by adding this before the where clause, but it just giving me back just column G not the SUM, I guess because of the constraint of the Where clause: SELECT A, B, C, ..., Sum(G) as SumTotal FROM YourTable WHERE D IN ('IA1', 'IA2', 'IA3') GROUP BY A, B, C ; Thank you!

Comment: I received the answer with this comment which did resolved the last request:
HAVING max(iif([D] like "IA1" .. rest of code)) IS NOT NULL OR max(iif([D] like "IA2" .. rest of code)) IS NOT NULL OR max(iif([D] like "IA3" .. rest of code)) IS NOT NULL

Instead of the where clause.

Thank you all :)